# File not found - API to submit Apache Spark jobs on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, restful-architecture

Context - 
Aim - API call from any machine that submits a Spark job to Spark EC2 cluster
Job runs perfectly well - Python file running on Localhost- Apache Spark
However, unable to run it on Apache Spark EC2.

Clarification -

> [Submitting jobs to Spark EC2 cluster remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666183/submitting-jobs-to-spark-ec2-cluster-remotely)
>   Refers to submitting jobs to Spark EC2 remotely - (but not via the API call)

API call

```
 curl -X POST http://ec2-54-209-108-127.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
  "appArgs" : [ "" ],
  "appResource" : "wordcount.py",
  "clientSparkVersion" : "1.5.0",
  "environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
  },
  "mainClass" : "",
  "sparkProperties" : {
    "spark.jars" : "wordcount.py",
    "spark.driver.supervise" : "true",
    "spark.app.name" : "MyJob",
    "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
    "spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
    "spark.master" : "spark://ec2-54-209-108-127.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6066"
  }}'
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20160712145703-0003",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160712145703-0003",
  "success" : true
}
```

To get the response, following API returns error - File not found

```
curl  http://ec2-54-209-108-127.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20160712145703-0003
{
  "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse",
  "driverState" : "ERROR",
  "message" : "Exception from the cluster:\njava.io.FileNotFoundException: wordcount.py (No such file or directory)\n\tjava.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)\n\tjava.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)\n\torg.spark-project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:124)\n\torg.spark-project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:114)\n\torg.spark-project.guava.io.ByteSource.copyTo(ByteSource.java:202)\n\torg.spark-project.guava.io.Files.copy(Files.java:436)\n\torg.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$copyRecursive(Utils.scala:539)\n\torg.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyFile(Utils.scala:510)\n\torg.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:595)\n\torg.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:394)\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$DriverRunner$$downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:150)\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:79)",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160712145703-0003",
  "success" : true,
  "workerHostPort" : "172.31.17.189:59433",
  "workerId" : "worker-20160712083825-172.31.17.189-59433"
}
```

Awaiting suggestions and improvements. 
p.s. - newbie in Apache Spark..

Update API call (Set the main class, appArgs, appResource, clientSparkVersion to updated value) ->

```
curl -X POST http://ec2-54-209-108-127.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6066/v1/submissions/create{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "/wordcount.py" ],
"appResource" : "file:/wordcount.py",
"clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
"environmentVariables" : {
"SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
"spark.app.name" : "Simple App",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://ec2-54-209-108-127.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6066"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the security group rules for your EC2 instance?

Comment: It has been kept open to all for all protocols

Comment: I tried with an updated API call - Still the error persists

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it seems, the error meant
Spark running on EC2 instance received the job submitted to it
It delegates the task to Worker 
Since the python application and related files Were not present on the Worker where the Application was supposed to run
It gave - File Not Found error
Thus, one has to Upload the Application in the EC2 and then ensure that the action is replicated across all the Worker nodes using

```
sudo /root/spark-ec2/copy-dir /root/wordcount.py 
RSYNC'ing /root/wordcount.py to slaves...
ec2-54-175-163-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

As a result, File Not Found error stopped. However, after re-submitting the Spark Job, the status of the Submission was

```
{
  "action": "SubmissionStatusResponse",
  "driverState": "FAILED",
  "serverSparkVersion": "1.6.1",
  "submissionId": "driver-20160713094138-0010",
  "success": true,
  "workerHostPort": "172.31.17.189:59433",
  "workerId": "worker-20160712083825-172.31.17.189-59433"
}
```

Hence not sure what is the exact error, whether it has been resolved or no and what is the new error