# Remote Spark standalone executor error

Tags: azure, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-spark-standalone

I am running a spark (2.0.1) standalone cluster on a remote server (Microsoft azure). I am able to connect my spark app to this cluster, however the tasks are getting stuck without any execution(with the following warning: 
`WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`)

What I have tried:

1. I have ensured that the memory, cpu requirements for my app do not exceed the server config.
2. Have supplied these variables to my `spark-env.sh` : `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS ,SPARK_DRIVER_HOST, SPARK_LOCAL_IP, SPARK_MASTER_HOST`
3. Can see the master / worker / application webui on the browser.
4. Have all the ports open on the remote server (for my IP and the vpn).
5. Disabled `ufw`.

As far as I can tell, my workers are not able to relay back to the master. Executors are timing out after 120s with the following stderr:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/11/19 18:15:09 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 17261@sparkmasternew
16/11/19 18:15:09 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/11/19 18:15:09 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/11/19 18:15:09 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/11/19 18:15:10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/19 18:15:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu,user1
16/11/19 18:15:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu,user1
16/11/19 18:15:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/11/19 18:15:10 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/11/19 18:15:10 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ubuntu, user1); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu, user1); groups with modify permissions: Set()
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: TransportClient has not yet been set.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcOutboxMessage.onTimeout(Outbox.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$ask$1.applyOrElse(NettyRpcEnv.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$ask$1.applyOrElse(NettyRpcEnv.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:138)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$onFailure$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$onFailure$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds
    ... 8 more
```

I am using my vm's private IP for `SPARK_DRIVER_HOST, SPARK_LOCAL_IP, SPARK_MASTER_HOST` and public IP as `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` and to connect to the master. The master and workers are running on the same vm. And this exact setup is working on an ec2 instance. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I am able to run spark-shell normally from within the machine. The problem seems to be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666183/submitting-jobs-to-spark-ec2-cluster-remotely) The executors can't interact with the driver, although I have the ports open on the vm. Is there a way to bind driver to the public IP of my instance/laptop?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if this is a single node, have you just installed it without making any changes to the conf?  I have an Ubuntu VM where i just downloaded the Spark bits, updated `.bashrc` for the `JAVA_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME` env variables.  As you already noted, if you're using multiple nodes, this trick won't work but for a single node, this should work.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I did change these SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS ,SPARK_DRIVER_HOST, SPARK_LOCAL_IP, SPARK_MASTER_HOST. Plus are you able to deploy an app from outside the vm? And yes everything is on a single vm for now.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my Q - are you able to connect to the cluster with the above changes (i.e. `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS`, ..., `SPARK_MASTER_HOST`) when logged into it locally (e.g. via spark-shell).  Oh, I have deployed apps outside of the VM but I had to do a bunch of changes to the network security group of the VM (and admittedly I haven't done that recently).

Comment: I am able to connect to the spark-shell locally but when I submit a job it gets gets stuck with the same message. I tried reverting back to the default config, same thing still.

Comment: I am now able to run spark-shell normally from within the machine. The problem seems to be similar to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666183/submitting-jobs-to-spark-ec2-cluster-remotely) The executors can't interact with the driver, although I have the ports open on the vm. Is there a way to bind driver to the public IP of my instance/laptop?

Comment: Glad to hear it!  As for connecting, if I recall correctly, it's about opening up the ports per [Apache Spark > Configuring Ports for Network security](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#configuring-ports-for-network-security).  I'll give it a try as well shortly.  BTW, to access the Spark UI remotely, I've been doing [ssh tunneling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-linux-ambari-ssh-tunnel); may be able to piggy back off of that method as well.